# Ordering data to match ggplot font faces

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm currently practicing my R using tidyverse/dpylr library.
So I re-used this example [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478264/how-to-reorder-cols-in-ggplot-geom-col-with-fill/55478908#55478908?newreg=f415d5fa6afd4031a3b323f06da341fd). I try to train with dpylr so i wanted to put value of muni_o bigger than 10 in bold in the y axis. I tried the following code:

```
pop=structure(list(muni_o = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
                                    21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
                                    34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
                                    9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
                                    22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
                                    35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
                                    10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
                                    23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
                                    36L, 37L, 38L, 39L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
                                                                    "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
                                                                    "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
                                                                    "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39"
                                    ), class = "factor"), muni_d2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
                                    ), .Label = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(6122.14220014045, 
                                                                                              14014.8937908602, 3212.98371738453, 3762.86973933326, 2036.58101043117, 
                                                                                              49935.7095757787, 5660.24459378729, 27133.6814011703, 8436.05010435109, 
                                                                                              1244.59144510279, 8192.3151623091, 5125.775303556, 5520.96031514796, 
                                                                                              971.04877757262, 13042.4320509421, 11677.9344908548, 23179.1486978947, 
                                                                                              19342.6692995674, 11480.8298502747, 773.75470216998, 658.84762129725, 
                                                                                              47303.8942738045, 12189.6600233976, 34138.2766548561, 2280.85569280618, 
                                                                                              6648.00527768305, 13731.4673121252, 6822.03535863008, 1654.5719919344, 
                                                                                              3408.63547537664, 8289.59920490436, 68250.529943451, 42919.3498777027, 
                                                                                              11304.5876393861, 1371.59278771158, 281250.973114875, 11758.2956764985, 
                                                                                              12160.5828034274, 4762.03601855022, 3774.00754913303, 17629.1897496886, 
                                                                                              450.28749520739, 11504.661338085, 2732.14923854684, 40180.8293143395, 
                                                                                              16562.6710623701, 43865.6430358497, 36647.9484766594, 7035.57607097289, 
                                                                                              25651.323071728, 26432.811604918, 23743.6986932767, 597.5643668538, 
                                                                                              124644.985934809, 29773.2098362482, 13788.9040158001, 24718.4440592384, 
                                                                                              6526.85217011751, 474.70640264902, 5440.01365034166, 29930.306857298, 
                                                                                              11072.6889810259, 101099.685991706, 254.95577591974, 11637.2716353329, 
                                                                                              5367.72912672273, 2504.81681919538, 97.98256049428, 2258.20425774592, 
                                                                                              8475.80585487552, 40564.9077830157, 59907.8345066714, 12858.502494956, 
                                                                                              850.24914346085, 0, 14152.3410516667, 41777.9839790016, 2730.8225408641, 
                                                                                              13662.2793985781, 46579.248451629, 5035.33799662119, 9167.68431269098, 
                                                                                              15713.4248568278, 36391.6173102699, 36523.5128982161, 56158.4213063058, 
                                                                                              17666.1932118543, 10319.0225229469, 14744.0900996851, 14519.6971048675, 
                                                                                              14341.9635886829, 5193.52143006156, 267285.439969485, 10049.4551896091, 
                                                                                              17861.0606322283, 56589.3203766755, 14836.888817694, 6069.4455916734, 
                                                                                              18992.3441918275, 52074.0110108799, 88973.5164027747, 82777.2109430964, 
                                                                                              2270.54970959312, 12030.813277725, 15414.1038338142, 3284.84133984456, 
                                                                                              3101.73291583232, 10020.5318813645, 25286.7675500444, 114919.563601638, 
                                                                                              185758.597625183, 28154.2996127091, 2873.4152126078, 3503521.52693064, 
                                                                                              49555.0928217366, 35402.2559957372, 7917.49624385274)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          -117L))
pop<-mutate(pop, COLORS=case_when(as.numeric(muni_o)>10~ 'bold',TRUE~ 'plain'))
pop %>% 
  group_by(muni_o) %>% 
  mutate(prop = Freq / sum(Freq)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(desc(muni_d2), prop) %>% 
  mutate(muni_o = factor(muni_o, levels = unique(muni_o))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(muni_o, prop, fill = muni_d2)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face =pop$COLORS,size=14))
```

The column I added COLORS seems correct. But I think my COLORS column is not modified to be associated with muni_o (because of the unique function use on muni_o) so the bold/plain order doesn't correspond. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the data frame you use for plotting has a different order than the original data frame `pop`. Hence the assignment between `COLORS` and `muni_o` is messed up. To prevent this save the df after your data wrangling as e.g. `pop1` and use `pop1$COLORS`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
pop<-mutate(pop, COLORS=case_when(as.numeric(muni_o)>10~ 'bold',TRUE~ 'plain'))
pop1 <- pop %>% 
  group_by(muni_o) %>% 
  mutate(prop = Freq / sum(Freq)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(desc(muni_d2), prop) %>% 
  mutate(muni_o = factor(muni_o, levels = unique(muni_o)))

pop1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(muni_o, prop, fill = muni_d2)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face =pop1$COLORS,size=14))
#> Warning: Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
#> Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.
```

[image]

Comment: Also possible to insert `ifelse` directly as an argument to the `face` attribute: `face = if_else(as.numeric(levels(pop1$muni_o)) > 10, 'bold', 'plain')`

Comment: Thanks for that 2 answers !